# How to reset the count/data after HTTP.POST?

Tags: nodemcu, http

I have a project that records interrupts from a reed switch to nodemcu.

It records like this: 0.3,0.6,0.9,1.2 Then what I want to happen is to go back to zero when it successfully HTTP.POST to a webserver.

How can I do it? Thanks!

```cpp
volatile float rainrate = 0.3;
volatile float total;

void count {
  total += rainrate;
}
```

Comment: So how do you set a variable to zero?

Comment: are micros() effective for this?

Comment: You are missing a lot of context on this question. Can you post the entire program?

Comment: Yea sorry, got it working already, after HTTP.POST, I put `total = 0;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting your `total` variable to `0`, like this:
`total = 0;`
It should work like this.

Comment: yea got it already, btw thanks for answering :)